Error when trying to install the stats package
install.packages("stats", dependencies = TRUE)


WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
Rtools before proceeding:
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
‘C:/Users/Dell/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’ (as ‘lib’ is
unspecified) Warning in install.packages :   package ‘stats’ is a base
package, and should not be updated

I installed RStudio for the first time. I have got this in red as soon as I open RStudio.


Why were you trying to install “stats”?  2) Tools is a set of system programs.     Not an R package.


stats is a "base" package, which means it is part of R, and can't be installed other than by upgrading all of R.  That's what the warning means.
The message about Rtools is something that RStudio will print if you are on Windows and try to install a package that contains C code (or some other languages) that needs compiling.  It doesn't really make sense that it would say this about stats, which can't be installed, but these things happen.
If you get that message when trying to install another package, then you should go to cran.r-project.org and follow the links to Rtools, and install it.  It gives you a bunch of tools that make Windows able to look like a Unix system (which is really where R is developed) and will let you install packages that need compiling.  It won't cause problems under Windows (other than using up a bunch of disk space), but will stop those messages from appearing.
